# Friendly url using php and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i have managed to change the url according to the values which i got from the database.
In my url i need to pass the article id and Article title like this.

```
$articleId=123;
$articleTitle='First Article';
echo '<a href="'.$articleId.'&'.str_replace(" ","-",$articleTitle).'">Read More</a>';
```

in my htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) display.php?id=$1&$2
```

Then on the Display.php i will get the Article Id using Get method.
But my problem is when i look the url it is displaying like this.

```
http://localhost/News/123&First-Article
```

But i need to display the url like this.

```
http://localhost/News/First-Article
```

and display the article details on Display.php file.
Hope i have clearly explain the problem. Please advice.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you need to have a unique title , what about `http://localhost/News/123/First-Article` ?

Comment: You will need a unique value for the news article and remove the `123` from the url means it won't be able to be used as a reference to identify the article.

Comment: @AbdouTahiri: Unique title can be done. but is there any way that we can do like above?.and change the url like you suggested  would be a fifth option.

Comment: @Howlin: hmm.if there are any other options, that would be the solution.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you just have to change this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) display.php?id=$1&$2
```

to that:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)[&](.+)$ display.php?id=$1/$2
```

Comment: The Query String has already been stripped off, so you won't see it in the RewriteRule.

Comment: @PhilPerry In the OPs question there is no hint of a query string. There is an anchor that points to some resource. So: _what_ query string?

Comment: The one you're referring to by having a **&** in the Rewrite pattern. What else is it there for?

Comment: That `&` is a character that _also_ serves as a delimiter in the query part of a url. But there is no query part in that url, there is no `?` that starts it. And using a `&` inside a reference to a resource is absolutely legal. So no, there is no query part in that url. Look at the anchor definition in the OPs question. Uncommon, but legal.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass only the title

```
echo '<a href="'.str_replace(" ","-",$articleTitle).'">Read More</a>';
```

*in .htaccess*

```
RewriteRule (.*) display.php?id=$1
```

so the `$_GET['id']` will take your article title directly .

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /News/(.*)&(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /News/%2/%3? [R,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^News/(.*)/(.*)$ /News/$1&$2 [L]
```

Which will display `http://localhost/News/123&First-Article` as `http://localhost/News/123/First-Article`

EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(.*)&(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3? [R,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /News/$1&$2 [L]
```

Comment: in this one, do we need the News Folder ?

Comment: In the url that is redirect to?

Comment: when i do like that it says Object not Found error message,why is that?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your htacces file?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /News/(.*)&(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /News/%2/%3? [R,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^News/(.*)/(.*)$ /News/$1&$2 [L]

Comment: Try change `RewriteRule ^News/(.*)/(.*)$ /News/$1&$2 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^Hurlingham/(.*)/(.*)$ /News/$1&$2 [L]`

Comment: Does the url change from `News/123&First-Article` to `Hurlingham/123/First-Article`

Comment: Where do you have the htaccess file located? It is in the root folder?

Comment: no inside the News Folder.do i have to place the htaccess file in the root folder

Comment: Yes, if you want to change `News` to something else

Comment: Let say if i don't need to change that and all i need is to display like this.News/123/First-Article?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Question that i have asked, most suitable answer would be to maintain a Unique article Name.

```
$articleTitle='First Article';
echo '<a href='.str_replace(" ","-",$articleTitle).'">Read More</a>';
```

And on your Htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) display.php?id=$1
```

then url will be like i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column in your database table "article_url_name" and use this function to create article url names and store in your database.

```
function make_url_name($title){
    $result =   "";

    $str    =   strtolower(stripslashes($str));
    $str    =   preg_replace("/ /i", "-", $str);

    for($n = 0; $n < strlen($str); $n++){
        if(preg_match("#^[a-z0-9-]+$#", $str[$n]))
            $result .=  $str[$n];
    }

    // Removing multiple ----
    $result =   preg_replace("/-----/i", "-", $result);
    $result =   preg_replace("/----/i", "-", $result);
    $result =   preg_replace("/---/i", "-", $result);
    $result =   preg_replace("/--/i", "-", $result);
    return $result;
}
```

put this like in your htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ articles.php?url_name=$1 [NC,L]
```

In "articles.php" file get the url name like this $_GET['url_name'];

And match this url_name to the 'article_url_name' column in your database table and display the articles content.

Answer (score 0):

If your **incoming** URI is

```
/News/First-Article
```

and you want your site to see

```
/display.php?id=First-Article
```

your .htaccess would be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteRule  ^News/([^/]+)/?  /display.php?id=$1  [L]
```

If "First-Article" is not unique enough, you would need to carry along a unique identifier in your URI:

```
/News/123/First-Article
```

and you want your site to see

```
/display.php?id=123&title=First-Article
```

your .htaccess would be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteRule  ^News/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$  /display.php?id=$1&title=$2  [QSA,L]
```

You can omit the title if it is not useful for locating the article. The QSA flag is to keep any existing incoming Query String variables (and just add id and title).